# Powershell - external command's parameter not accepted

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, dfs

This seems like a simple problem but I am unable to fix it

Running dfsutil command in shell returns result

```
C:\Windows\system32>dfsutil link "\server.domain.com\DFSRootname\Sharename"
```

Link Name="Sharename" State="OK" Timeout="1800"
        Target="\server1\sharename" State="ONLINE"  [Site: site1]
        Target="\server2\sharename" State="OFFLINE"  [Site: site2]

Done processing this command.

Trying to do the same in powershell

```
PS>
$path = "\\server.domain.com\DFSRootname\Sharename"
$dfsutil = "dfsutil"
$option = "link"

PS C:\Windows\system32> dfsutil link $path

DFS Utility Version 5.2 (built on 5.2.3790.3959)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Unrecognized option "ink"
```

Same with using Invoke-Expression

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Expression "$dfsutil $option $path"

DFS Utility Version 5.2 (built on 5.2.3790.3959)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Unrecognized option "ink"
```

Answer (score 3):

The following syntax works for me on PS v2/v3.  I'm preceding the command with a `&` [the Call Operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx#The_Call_Operator_amp):

```
$path = "\\ad.example.org\root\share"
$dfsutil = "dfsutil"
$option = "link"

& $dfsutil $option $path

Link Name="share" State="OK" Timeout="1800"
Target="\\fs1.example.org\share" State="ONLINE"  [Site: default-site]

Done processing this command.
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. This is what I expected to happen. Seems like problem only happens on my Windows 7 PS3 install. Command works fine on Windows 2008 R2 host wint PS2 it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Seems like installation problem with my Windows 7 PS3 install. Command works fine on Windows 2008 R2 host with PS2